# Why do logins usually can contain only latin symbols and digits?

Tags: mysql, forms, interface

Is this just an user experience thing?
Or it's historically?
I mean, here is no difference which characters to store in database. And all special characters will be encoded anyways. So what's the matter?

Comment: "I mean, here is no difference which characters to store in database." Storing password characters in the database is a very bad approach. You should store a salted hash along with the "salt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an artifact of history: a holdover from the olden days of UNIX usernames.  They used to be limited to eight characters too; fortunately we don't still cling to that particular tradition.

If you're creating a web site today, you can certainly define your `username` column with the `utf8mb4` or `utf8` character set. Then your users' names can include all sorts of characters from worldwide languages, and emojis, and other glyphs.

Please do think through the requirements for case sensitivity in these enhanced usernames, and set the collation for your `username` column appropriately.